# sequential execution chaining of async operations in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, sequential-workflow

Is there any primitive in the langage to compose async1 **then** async2, akin to what parallel does for parallel execution planning ?

to further clarify, I have 2 async computations

```
  let toto1 = Async.Sleep(1000)
  let toto2 = Async.Sleep(1000)
```

I would like to create a new async computation made of the sequential composition of toto1 and toto2

```
  let toto = Async.Sequential [|toto1; toto2|]
```

upon start, toto would run toto1 then toto2, and would end after 2000 time units

Comment: What is there to "try" here ? yeah I "tried" answering my question reading the API on msdn..

Comment: Is [`Async.StartChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370511.aspx) what you want?

Comment: I saw this, but it looks like StartChild forks a new parallel child upon execution.

Comment: @nicolas You didn't even indicate that you'd read anything. By telling us what you've looked at or showing code that you've tried to solve this you can prevent us from duplicating or responding as if you've just decided to ask rather than do anything.

Comment: @Lazarus I am asking about a primitive of the langage. there is nothing to "try".

Comment: @nicolas I would call looking at the documentation "trying" to find an answer, wouldn't you? That said `Async` isn't a primitive, it's part of the .Net Framework. You're going to need to move up into the framework and write some code. Couldn't you use a continuation that spawns async2?

Comment: @Lazarus I would call that 'common sense'

Comment: @nicolas Look through more of the other questions... you'll find common sense really isn't all that common ;)

Comment: What's `toto` in your example? Is it the result of `toto1` or `toto2`?   What do you want to do with the other result? Ignore it? Do you want to combine them? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `async.Bind` operation is the basic *primitive* that asynchronous workflows provide for sequential composition - in the `async` block syntax, that corresponds to `let!`. You can use that to express sequential composition of two computations (as demonstrated by Daniel).

However, if you have an operation `<|>` that Daniel defined, than that's not expressive enough to implement `async.Bind`, because when you compose things sequentially using `async.Bind`, the second computation may depend on the result of the first one. The `<e2>` may use `v1`:

```
async.Bind(<e1>, fun v1 -> <e2>)
```

If you were writing `<e1> <|> <e2>` then the two operations have to be independent. This is a reason why the libraries are based on `Bind` - because it is more expressive form of sequential composition than the one you would get if you were following the structure of `Async.Parallel`.

If you want something that behaves like `Async.Parallel` and takes an array, then the easiest option is to implement that imperatively using `let!` in a loop (but you could use recursion and lists too):

```
let Sequential (ops:Async<'T>[]) = async {
  let res = Array.zeroCreate ops.Length
  for i in 0 .. ops.Length - 1 do
    let! value = ops.[i]
    res.[i] <- value 
  return res }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this function any differently than `async1 <|> async2 <|> ... asyncN` using the combinator in my answer?

Comment: Of interest is that it is **not** Async.Bind, but **async.Bind** I had missed entirely this, and was looking at the control.Async module in MSDN. (Might be good to add this to Async for regularity)

Comment: @nicolas Ah, yes, sorry for the confusion :-) The `Bind` operation is poart of the async computation builder (the `async` value) which is used in the translation of `async { .. }` block. Additional combinators are exposed in a module (as static members).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "primitive." `Async.Parallel` is a function. Here are a few ways to run two asyncs:

In parallel:

```
Async.Parallel([|async1; async2|])
```

or

```
async {
  let! child = Async.StartChild async2
  let! result1 = child
  let! result2 = async1
  return [|result1; result2|]
}
```

Sequentially:

```
async {
  let! result1 = async1
  let! result2 = async2
  return [|result1; result2|]
}
```

You could return tuples in the last two. I kept the return types the same as the first one.

I would say `let!` and `do!` in an `async { }` block is as close as you'll get to using a primitive for this.

#### EDIT

If all this nasty syntax is getting to you, you could define a combinator:

```
let (<|>) async1 async2 = 
  async {
    let! r1 = async1
    let! r2 = async2
    return r1, r2
  }
```

and then do:

```
async1 <|> async2 |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: by primitive, I mean a function that is not made of a combination simpler functions, aka something in the langage.

Comment: `let!` and `do!` are syntactic sugar for continuations, which is what you want. Are they not "primitive" enough?

Comment: thank you Daniel, I figured out early I could write a combinator, but just like there is one for // computations, I was just wondering if another was hidden somewhere.

Comment: May be they did not add it as it is not as straightforward if you want to handle the general case with composition, where types of the call chain have to be compatible. for unit, of course it is trivial. (actually for unlimited sequence it is probably not representable in the type system)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think a general-purpose `bind` is possible. You can't know, for every `M<'T>`, which values of `'T` are failure/success.